# Why directory copied with cp command has less size than the original one

Tags: command-line, cp, du

I am tying to copy one directory with big amount of files to another destination. I did

```
cp -r src_dir another_destination/
```

Then I wanted to confirm that the size of the destination directory is the same as the original one:

```
du -s src_dir
3782288 src_dir

du -s another_destination/src_dir
3502320 another_destination/src_dir
```

Then I had a thought that there might be several symbolic links that are not followed by `cp` command and added `-a` flag:

> -a    Same as -pPR options. Preserves structure and attributes of files but not directory structure.

```
cp -a src_dir another_destination/
```

but `du -s` gave me the same results. It is interesting that the both source and destination have the same amount of files and directories:

```
tree src_dir | wc -l
    4293

tree another_destination/src_dir | wc -l
    4293
```

What I am doing wrong that I get different sizes with the `du` command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can have a number of reasons because you are asking for the used disk size, not for the amount of bytes stored in both trees.

- In a file system files are stored with a specific amount of overhead.  This overhead depends on the file system.  Maybe the two storages are using different file systems which are not equally efficient (use different block sizes for example which might be due to different disk sizes).
- Another reason might be hardlinked files in the original.  The copy might have copied the hardlinked files several times so that in the copy they aren't hardlinked anymore.
- A third reason might be sparse files which contain large areas of zero-bytes which in some file systems can be efficiently stored by assigning them no blocks.

To rule out at least the first reason (the most likely one), I propose to use `du -bs` on both trees.

Comment: Would you tell why the size of directory name is different in two partitions? In a system, the /home partition shows all the directory name has 4096 byte which I think it is normal. But in a different partition /home3, the sizes of directory names are completely different such as 161, 287, 273, including 4096. I do not understand this system completely but can you give me some idea? It looks the filesystem in /etc/fstab look same.

Comment: File systems can be optimized for specific purposes, e.g. for containing mostly large files (but not so many) or for containing an immense amount of small files.  Depending on the concrete usecase in many filesystems like ext4 or similar you can pass corresponding parameters to the formatting command (e.g. mkfs.ext4).  One result will be the maximal number of files in the file sestem, another will be the mean number of bytes of overhead per file (due to partially filled blocks), and yet another is how many bytes directories take up.